# Iframe Scroll to top of page on load with tabs

Tags: javascript, iframe, tabs

I have an i-frame of a "design your own uniform" app within a page. The design your own uniform app consists of four tabs (select product, select colours, insert details, receive quote).

Each time I go to a new tab the page stays at the same horizontal position as the previous tab. Is there a way that I can make the page load at the top of the i-frame from tab to tab?

I've seen this done with js, however I've never seen a specific example where tabs are involved.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

bigscreentv

Answer (score 0):

you should use scrollto function

html

```
    <a href='#id'>btn</a>
    <div id='id'></div>

$('a').click(function() {
    var elementClicked = $(this).attr("href");
    var destination = $(elementClicked).offset().top;
    $("html:not(:animated),body:not(:animated)").animate({ scrollTop: destination-15}, 500 );
    return false;
});
```